# Escape space in filepath

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a python tool that will read a logfile and process it

One thing it should do is use the paths listed in the logfile (it's a logfile for a backup tool)

```
/Volumes/Live_Jobs/Live_Jobs/*SCANS\ and\ LE\ Docs/_LE_PROOFS_DOCS/JEM_lj/JEM/0002_OXO_CorkScrew/3\ Delivery/GG_Double\ Lever\ Waiters\ Corkscrew_072613_Mike_RETOUCHED/gg_3110200_2_V3_Final.tif
```

Unfortunately the paths that I'm provided with aren't appropriately escaped and I've had trouble properly escaping in python. Perhaps python isn't the best tool for this, but I like it's flexibility - it will allow me to extend whatever I write

Using the regex escape function escapes too many characters, pipes.quote method doesn't escape the spaces, and if I use a regex to replace ' ' with '\ ' I end up getting

```
/Volumes/Live_Jobs/Live_Jobs/*SCANS\\ and\\ LE\\ Docs/_LE_PROOFS_DOCS/JEM_lj/JEM/0002_OXO_CorkScrew/3\\ Delivery/GG_Double\\ Lever\\ Waiters\\ Corkscrew_072613_Mike_RETOUCHED/gg_3110200_2_V3_Final.tif
```

which are double escaped and wont pass to python functions like `os.path.getsize()`.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Do you actually need to escape the paths? There are tools that don't require escaping; the ones that do are generally considered unsafe. What do you need to do with the paths?

Comment: Could you try putting an `r` in front of the string value? That way, Python will treat the whole thing as a literal. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: @user2357112: … and the tools that don't require escaping including the built-in `open` function, and just about every other function in Python except for a handful like `os.system`…

Comment: I'm not trying to open the file, and as you saw I'm using the built in tool os.path.getsize(). It does require escaping and I have tried putting the r in my replace and it doesn't help.

Comment: @user2666063: No, `os.path.getsize()` does not require escaping. Do this from your shell: `mkdir "dir with spaces"; touch "dir with spaces/file with spaces"`. Then run [this 2-line Python script](http://pastebin.com/fcLw8t7g). It will successfully print out `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're reading paths out of a file, and passing them to functions like `os.path.getsize`, you don't need to escape them. For example:

```
>>> with open('name with spaces', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('abc\n')
>>> os.path.getsize('name with spaces')
4
```

In fact, there are only a handful of functions in Python that need spaces escaped, either because they're passing a string to the shell (like `os.system`) or because they're trying to do shell-like parsing on your behalf (like `subprocess.foo` with an arg string instead of an arg list).

---

So, let's say `logfile.txt` looks like this:

```
/Volumes/My Drive/My Scans/Batch 1/foo bar.tif
/Volumes/My Drive/My Scans/Batch 1/spam eggs.tif
/Volumes/My Drive/My Scans/Batch 2/another long name.tif
```

… then something like this will work fine:

```
with open('logfile.txt') as logf:
    for line in logf:
        with open(line.rstrip()) as f:
            do_something_with_tiff_file(f)
```

Noticing those `*` characters in your example, if these are glob patterns, that's fine too:

```
with open('logfile.txt') as logf:
    for line in logf:
        for path in glob.glob(line.rstrip()):
            with open(path) as f:
                do_something_with_tiff_file(f)
```

---

If your problem is the exact opposite of what you described, and the file is full of strings that *are* escaped, and you want to unescape them, `decode('string_escape')` will undo Python-style escaping, and there are different functions to undo different kinds of escaping, but without knowing what kind of escaping you want to undo it's hard to say which function you want…

Comment: .rstrip() did not work for me, got spaces in the file names

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds Yes, and? Spaces in the filenames are perfectly fine, as the answer explains.

Comment: they are so fine I get erros opening them with open(...) function

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds I don't know what your problem is, but you probably need to create a new question. You can click the `share` icon to get a link to post to this answer or the question if it's relevant. Then provide a [mcve] showing what you're doing and what errors you get.

Comment: @abarnert - How would you handle processing a string before sending to os.system()?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
  myfile = open(r'c:\tmp\junkpythonfile','w')
```

The 'r' stands for a raw string.

You could also use \ like

```
myfile = open('c:\\tmp\\junkpythonfile','w')
```

Comment: r stands for raw string, not raw file

Comment: I will try your first suggestion, but I'm not sure what your second suggestion would entail as I'm on a unix like system

Comment: None of this is relevant on a Unix system. And none of it is relevant unless your strings are literals in the source code; if you're reading them from a file (as explained in the question), there is no literal to raw-ify.

Answer (score 0):

This command will escape the spaces in a string.

```
# sample_string = sample_string.replace(key, value)
file_path = file_path.replace(' ','\ ')
```

For more details see [https://thispointer.com/python-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string](https://thispointer.com/python-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string/#:%7E:text=Python%3A%20Replace%20multiple%20characters%20in%20a%20string%20using%20the%20replace,of%20a%20character%20data%20type.)

Comment: As the accepted answers states, there's no need to escape the spaces in this case. But if this was about escaping spaces, that actually does not work. You cannot just put \ in front of *any* character to escape it. In order to actually print a space, you would have to use '\x20' or you could use '\t' to print a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use shlex to secape filenames where needed.

```
import shlex

# Example filename with spaces and brackets
filename = '/path/to/my file [with spaces].txt'

# Escape the filename
escaped_filename = shlex.quote(filename)

# Print the escaped filename
print(escaped_filename)
```