# problems with wavfile.py showing a unexpected error

Tags: python, scipy

i wrote this function a while ago it was working for a while then this happened help me

> track is mp3 file cmd converts mp3 into temp.wav file

```
def convertwmv(track):
    oname = 'temp.wav'
    cmd='lame --decode {0} {1}'.format( track,oname )
    os.system(cmd)
    data=wav.read(oname)
    return data
```

**Error:**

```
   sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

  File "/home/mako/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 233, in read
    fid = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp.wav'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the file 'temp.wav' in the same directory as the one you are in? How do you run the script?

Comment: @jaivalis yes if os.system(cmd) executes temp.wav will be created

Comment: Try providing it with a full path if you're running it from a different directory or replace the path with './temp.wav'. The '.' indicates to look in the same directory

Comment: @jaivalis im getting this weird syntax error can u help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the track name you are using might be having some brackets in it's file name. bash commands don't deal well with special characters and spaces. Try to escape them before formatting your cmd variable. It became apparent after your last edit.

Comment: can u tel how to do that

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18137194/574975 by @abamert